# How to do a professional setup for java app to avoid "javaw" cannot be found?

Tags: java

I just installed http://yacy.net/

It advertises as easy install except that when I run it says cannot find javaw which spoils nearly everything.

If I were to distribute a java app myself I'd like not to have user knows anything about downloading and installing java, so any article, tool which explains how to package a java app professionally like one can do with a windows app easily ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339910/how-can-i-detect-the-installed-sun-jre-on-windows if you want to create a custom launcher from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to this, all of which have their own set of drawbacks. Here are some of the most popular:

- Bundle a private JRE with your application. See the [README file](http://download.java.net/dlj/jre/README) that comes with your JRE for the details.
- Use a launcher (such as [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)) that can download a JRE at runtime if a suitable one is not found on the target machine.
- Compile Java to native, then distribute as a regular Win32/Linux executable. You can do this with [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/).

Since you are concerned with deployment, you'll probably also want to create an installer for your application. There are dozens of options for this, such as [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).