# NSIS script for java installation

Tags: java, installation, nsis

I want to install Java using an NSIS script, but i have to know whether Java is installed or not in the system (Windows). based on the register keys how can we check if Java is installed or not?

Can anybody provide an NSIS script to check Java installation based on registery keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't compile it, but I would try following. I chose registry key based on [How can I detect the installed Sun JRE on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339910/how-can-i-detect-the-installed-sun-jre-on-windows).

```
;--------------------------------
;Defines

  !define JavaRegKey 'HKLM "Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" ""'

;--------------------------------
;Installer Sections
Section 'Java Runtime' SecJava

  SetOutPath '$TEMP'
  SetOverwrite on
  File 'c:\<yourdir>\javasetup.exe'
  ExecWait '$TEMP\javasetup.exe' $0
  DetailPrint '..Java Runtime Setup exit code = $0'
  Delete '$TEMP\javasetup.exe'

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------
;   Functions
Function .onInit

  ReadRegStr $R0 ${JavaRegKey}
  StrCmp $R0 "" JavaMissing JavaFound

  JavaFound: 
  !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecJava}
  Goto JavaCheckDone

  JavaMissing:
  !insertmacro SelectSection ${SecJava}

  JavaCheckDone:

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 3):

The following fragment of code checks if Java is installed (jre or jdk).
If Java is not installed, it will install it.
The script also saves the path to Java in a variable `$JavaInstallationPath`.

```
Var JavaInstallationPath
Section "Find Java" FINDJAVA    
    DetectTry1:
    StrCpy $1 "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"  
    StrCpy $2 0  
    ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "$1" "CurrentVersion"  
    StrCmp $2 "" DetectTry2 JRE 
    JRE:
    ReadRegStr $5 HKLM "$1\$2" "JavaHome"  
    StrCmp $5 "" DetectTry2 GetValue    

    DetectTry2:  
    ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" "CurrentVersion"  
    StrCmp $2 "" NoJava JDK 
    JDK:
    ReadRegStr $5 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\$2" "JavaHome"  
    StrCmp $5 "" NoJava GetValue

    GetValue:
    StrCpy $JavaInstallationPath $5
    Messagebox MB_OK "Javahome value: $JavaInstallationPath"
    Goto done

    NoJava:  
    Messagebox MB_OK "No Java installation detected. Installing Java."  
    # Install Java
    ExecWait "$INSTDIR\java\jre-6u26-windows-i586.exe"
    Goto DetectTry1

    done:   
    #$JavaInstallationPath should contain the system path to Java
SectionEnd
```

I think you can also put the above code in a function and call it wherever you like in your NSIS script.

Answer (score 3):

Another example with online jre installer and 64/32 bit check

java min version

```
!define JRE_VERSION_6 "1.5"
```

check function

```
Function DetectJRE
  ;64bit jre und jdk check
  SetRegView 64
  ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" \
             "CurrentVersion"
  ;StrCmp $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} done
  ${VersionCompare} $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} $R0
  StrCmp $R0 "1" done

  ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" \
             "CurrentVersion"
  ;StrCmp $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} done
  ${VersionCompare} $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} $R0
  StrCmp $R0 "1" done

  ;32bit jre und jdk check
  SetRegView 32
  ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" \
             "CurrentVersion"
  ;StrCmp $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} done
  ${VersionCompare} $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} $R0
  StrCmp $R0 "1" done

  ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit" \
             "CurrentVersion"
  ;StrCmp $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} done
  ${VersionCompare} $2 ${JRE_VERSION_6} $R0
  StrCmp $R0 "1" done


  Call GetJRE
  done:
FunctionEnd
```

version compare

```
Function VersionCompare
    !define VersionCompare `!insertmacro VersionCompareCall`

    !macro VersionCompareCall _VER1 _VER2 _RESULT
        Push `${_VER1}`
        Push `${_VER2}`
        Call VersionCompare
        Pop ${_RESULT}
    !macroend

    Exch $1
    Exch
    Exch $0
    Exch
    Push $2
    Push $3
    Push $4
    Push $5
    Push $6
    Push $7

    begin:
    StrCpy $2 -1
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    StrCpy $3 $0 1 $2
    StrCmp $3 '' +2
    StrCmp $3 '.' 0 -3
    StrCpy $4 $0 $2
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    StrCpy $0 $0 '' $2

    StrCpy $2 -1
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    StrCpy $3 $1 1 $2
    StrCmp $3 '' +2
    StrCmp $3 '.' 0 -3
    StrCpy $5 $1 $2
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
    StrCpy $1 $1 '' $2

    StrCmp $4$5 '' equal

    StrCpy $6 -1
    IntOp $6 $6 + 1
    StrCpy $3 $4 1 $6
    StrCmp $3 '0' -2
    StrCmp $3 '' 0 +2
    StrCpy $4 0

    StrCpy $7 -1
    IntOp $7 $7 + 1
    StrCpy $3 $5 1 $7
    StrCmp $3 '0' -2
    StrCmp $3 '' 0 +2
    StrCpy $5 0

    StrCmp $4 0 0 +2
    StrCmp $5 0 begin newer2
    StrCmp $5 0 newer1
    IntCmp $6 $7 0 newer1 newer2

    StrCpy $4 '1$4'
    StrCpy $5 '1$5'
    IntCmp $4 $5 begin newer2 newer1

    equal:
    StrCpy $0 0
    goto end
    newer1:
    StrCpy $0 1
    goto end
    newer2:
    StrCpy $0 2

    end:
    Pop $7
    Pop $6
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
FunctionEnd
```

getJre

```
Function GetJRE
    MessageBox MB_YESNO "XXXXXX require at least Java 1.5! Do you want to download and install it now?" IDYES doInstall

    Abort
    doInstall:
    StrCpy $2 "$TEMP\Java Runtime Environment.exe"
    nsisdl::download /TIMEOUT=30000 ${JRE_URL} $2
    Pop $R0 ;Get the return value
        StrCmp $R0 "success" +3
        MessageBox MB_OK "Download failed: $R0"
        Quit
    ExecWait $2
    Delete $2  

    Call DetectJRE
FunctionEnd
```

if theire is something missing you will find it at nsis-wiki page