# Can I create a standalone .exe installer for a Java application with Inno Setup?

Tags: java, windows, inno-setup

Can all those steps be accomplished with Inno Setup or do I need additional software?

- Create a standalone `.exe` installer for a Java application (either a main JAR plus libraries or a Uber JAR)
- Bundle a JRE
- Create a Desktop shortcut so users can start the application manually if necessary
- Set up the application to run on startup

The answer could be either "yes" or "no, you would need the following additional software...".

Unless it's considered too broad a basic script would be appreciated too, but this is optional.

Comment: Hello downvoter, I want to improve my question, please let me know how I can improve it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of INNO setup, I use NSIS (https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/), it's open source software, and very powerful, you can use script.

- Create a standanlone .exe installer for a Java application (either a main JAR plus libraries or a Uber JAR)

  A: Yes, you need additional software like Launch4j(http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) , or if you use Eclipse or IDEA there is built-in tools to create executable application
- Bundle a JRE

  A: Yes, use NSIS script you can bundle JRE installation
- Create a Desktop shortcut so users can start the application manually if necessary

  A: Yes, use NSIS script you can Create a Desktop shortcut
- Set up the application to run on startup

  A: Yes, NSIS script you can write  windows registry. depends on where you put, Programs defined in Run, RunOnce or StartUp will be loaded in following order:
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
  StartUp Folder
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think Launch4j is necessary. I want to turn the JRE + JAR application bundle into an .exe, not the JAR application alone. Besides, Launch4j does not allow bundling of a JRE.

Comment: Would you have further suggestions in that case? (P.S.: sorry, I sounded a bit dry in my comment, that was unintentional)

Comment: you can use NSIS script to turn the JRE + JAR application bundle into a installation EXE, take a look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000386/nsis-script-for-java-installation