# Run executable jar from batch - how to specify java home dir?

Tags: java, batch-file, executable

I'm running a little terminal jar tool by batch with:

```
%cd%
"c:\program files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java" -jar myfile.jar
```

But for every new machine I'm running this, I have to first check and edit the path to java home. Is there any batch way to not have to edit this all the time, but automating the java-homedir finding?

Comment: You could check the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` although that is not always set either. Why don't you just rely on the installer having put `java.exe` into the `PATH`?

Comment: because eg for the machine I'm currently working on there is NO java command available, no path. And cannot be set due to missing admin rights.

Comment: Or you can attempt to call java ( `java -jar ...` ) without the path with hope that if it was installed than it will be in the path.

Comment: You don't need admin rights to change the (user specific) `PATH` variable.

Comment: The JRE installer should put an executable in the system directory (which will be on your path.) The `-version:foo` switch can be used to select a specific version. See also [How can I detect the installed Sun JRE on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339910)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can check in order:

1. JAVA_HOME environment variable.
2. java executable in the path.
3. `reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\"` to list all yours java runtimes.

With the last command you can see the CurrentVersion and with `reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\your_version_number"` you will find the java home dir.

If all previous methods fail you need to scan the file system to find a java binary :(.